# C# String.Remove() почему не срабатывает

Tags: c#, строки

Я не понимаю почему такое простейшие действие не может сработать. Код возвращает ту же строку

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i<str.Length-1; i++){
   if (str[i]==str[i+1]){
       Console.WriteLine("yep");
       str.Remove(i,i);
   }
}


Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема состояла в том что медот Remove не изменяет строку напрямую, иначе надо делать присваивание `str = str.Remove(i,i)`

Comment: Чтоб в будущем не попасть на такое, пока новичок в языке, следуйте подсказкам студии, смотрите внимательно сигнатуру метода, что требует, что возвращает, и так далее. В C# много таких мест.